# What does "ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable TCMText is not defined" mean?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

When you click a circle it should double in size.  However I get the error:

**ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable TCMText is not defined.**

I think it's because I selected both the text and circle and made the selection a single symbol.  Does anyone know how to combine a shape and symbol together without getting this error message?

[image]

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

circOne.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doubleSize);
circTwo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doubleSize);
circThree.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doubleSize);

function doubleSize(event:MouseEvent):void{
    e.currentTarget.scaleX=2;
    e.currentTarget.scaleY=2;
}
```

Comment: Hi, just making sure this isn't it, in your example you wrote `e` instead of `event`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides that runtime error, you are getting **Compiler errors**, fix your code as @recursivity said:

```
function doubleSize(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.scaleX=2;
    e.currentTarget.scaleY=2;
}
```

**Check the "Compiler Errors" tabs, and if you are getting any, you can pretty much ignore any further output and behavior you get from your Flash.**

EDIT: There is absolutely nothing wrong on selecting many different elements together and then making them (or "combining") into a Symbol (MovieClip).

The reason you are getting a runtime **ReferenceError** AFTER a compiler error (which is a very weird behavior) is because you are using **TLF textfields**, check [this thread on the adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3737141#3737141) for more information. My advice, for the sake of simplicity, is to switch to **Classic Text** textfields (There is a dropdown selector in the TextField properties panel, TLF is by default on Flash CS5+).

Answer (score -1):

My TCMText error got triggered when I used new Rectangle to draw a shape and add it to the stage. Drawing the rectangle didn't trigger the error. The error popped up when I went to add it the stage. The same thing happened when I then tried to draw the rectangle using Shape and graphics.rect. I finally got my rectangle without the TCMText error by using Shape and moveTo/lineTo. On the Adobe forum someone states that there's no option to disable this.